# Find the dimension the subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

how can I find the dimension the subespace of R(x)_3 which is defined by
(p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d;p(-1)=0)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$0=p(-1)=-a+b-c+d$$

How many freedom degrees do you have to *choose* the coefficients $\;a,b,c,d\;$ so that the above will be true? That'll give you the dimension. Why? Well, try to choose a basis for your subspace, for example..

Comment: Well, I am still not seeing how can I go further.

Comment: Have you **already** given it a good *thought* ?? You must have done things like this one when, for example, you solved homogeneous linear systems of equations...!